# How not to select same row when selecting random records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table with tens of thousands of records which has pre-generated codes. I give one randomly selected code to a user each time. I select one code and immediately update it as "used". My problem is every once in a while two users get the same code. Is there a guaranteed way to not give two users the same code?

This is how I select and update the selected code:

```
SELECT TOP 1 @code = code FROM MyCodes WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE used = 0 and some other conditions
 AND 0.01 >= CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(), code) & 0x7fffffff AS FLOAT) / CAST (0x7fffffff AS INT);

UPDATE MyCodes SET used = 1 WHERE code = @code;
```

Comment: Why pre-generate the codes? Generate and give to the user as it happens.

Comment: Your random selection isn't a uniform selection from all the available unused codes. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Mark: I already have that condition just forgot to put it in the question code sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can run both statements in a transaction and only give the code to the user if committing the transaction succeeds.

You also need to have `WHERE used = 0` in your SELECT query, but I assume that is covered by this?

```
 ... WHERE some conditions AND ...
```

Also you don't want that NO LOCK there.

Comment: What will happen if the same code is selected by two transactions? Will the second one wait for the first ones lock to release and select the same one after release?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE MyCodes SET used = 1 WHERE code = @code and used=0
```

see the `@@ROWCOUNT` and if it's zero make a different decision , throw an error or try again